# Недоступна функция родительского класса и недоступно преобразование в него

Tags: c++

Есть класс:

```
class Shape  {  // deals with color and style, and holds sequence of lines
protected:
    Shape() { }
    Shape(initializer_list<Point> lst);  // add() the Points to this Shape

//  Shape() : lcolor(fl_color()),
//      ls(0),
//      fcolor(Color::invisible) { }

    void add(Point p){ points.push_back(p); }
    void set_point(int i, Point p) { points[i] = p; }
public:
    void draw() const;                  // deal with color and draw_lines
protected:
    virtual void draw_lines() const;    // simply draw the appropriate lines
public:
    virtual void move(int dx, int dy);  // move the shape +=dx and +=dy

    void set_color(Color col) { lcolor = col; }
    Color color() const { return lcolor; }

    void set_style(Line_style sty) { ls = sty; }
    Line_style style() const { return ls; }

    void set_fill_color(Color col) { fcolor = col; }
    Color fill_color() const { return fcolor; }

    Point point(int i) const { return points[i]; }
    int number_of_points() const { return int(points.size()); }

    virtual ~Shape() { }
    /*
    struct Window* attached;
    Shape(const Shape& a)
        :attached(a.attached), points(a.points), line_color(a.line_color), ls(a.ls)
    {
        if (a.attached)error("attempt to copy attached shape");
    }
    */
    Shape(const Shape&) = delete;
    Shape& operator=(const Shape&) = delete;
private:
    vector<Point> points;   // not used by all shapes
    Color lcolor {fl_color()};
    Line_style ls {0};
    Color fcolor {Color::invisible};

//  Shape(const Shape&);
//  Shape& operator=(const Shape&);
};
```

Создаю производный класс:

```
class Arc : Shape
    {
    public:
        Arc(Point p, int ww, int hh, double ang) : angle{ ang }, w{ ww }, h{ hh }
        {
            add(Point{ p.x - ww, p.y - hh });
        }

        void draw_lines() const;

        Point center() const { return{ point(0).x + w, point(0).y + h }; }
        Point focus1() const { return{ center().x + int(sqrt(double(w*w - h * h))), center().y }; }
        Point focus2() const { return{ center().x - int(sqrt(double(w*w - h * h))), center().y }; }

        void set_major(int ww) { w = ww; }
        int major() const { return w; }
        void set_minor(int hh) { h = hh; }
        int minor() const { return h; }

    private:
        int w;
        int h;
        double angle;
    };
```

Использую его:

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        Simple_window win{ Point{100, 100}, 800, 600, "1" };

        Graph_lib::Arc arc{ Point{200, 200}, 50, 50, 70 };
        arc.set_color(Color::black);

        win.attach(arc);

        win.wait_for_button();

    }
    catch (const std::exception&e)
    {
        cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        keep_window_open();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Но не могу использовать функции родительского класса, в частности set_color(), и не могу преобразовать его в Shape в win.attach(arc):

> error C2247: нет доступа к "Graph_lib::Shape::set_color", поскольку
>   "Graph_lib::Arc" использует "private" для наследования из
>   "Graph_lib::Shape" error C2243: приведение типов: преобразование
>   "Graph_lib::Arc *" в "Graph_lib::Shape &" существует, но недоступно

Comment: А как вы себя представляете обьект "форма"?   Такой базовый класс должен быть абстрактным

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас используется private наследование, поэтому все методы родительского класса являются private в дочернем. Скорее всего вам нужно использовать public наследование:

```
class Arc: public Shape {
  ...
}
```

Comment: А почему используется private наследование? Вроде же, если не указывать модификатор доступа, используется public.

Comment: @CheshireCat, для `struct` модификатор доступа по умолчанию `public `, для `class` - `private`